# Sort the order before concatenating

Tags: sorting, sparql, wikidata

I have a Wikidata SPRQL script that begins like this:

```
SELECT
      (group_concat(distinct     ?dateYear ; separator = ", ") AS     ?dateYears)
      (group_concat(distinct  ?gameENLabel ; separator = ", ") AS  ?gameENLabels)
      WHERE {
        VALUES ?game {
          wd:Q4850488
          wd:Q4931588
          wd:Q5315330
        }
        ?game rdfs:label ?gameENLabel.
        FILTER(LANG(?gameENLabel) = "en").
        OPTIONAL {
          ?game wdt:P577 ?date.
          BIND(YEAR(?date) AS ?dateYear).
        }
        SERVICE wikibase:label {
          bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en".
       }
      }
    GROUP BY $game
order by desc(?dateYears)
```

Can I sort the `?dateYear` values before concatenating them? Thanks.

Comment: You can try to get the dates in a sub-select and sorted - but without using the distinct in the `group_concat`

Comment: If you show the rest of the query, an answer might be given - but currently I can't test it.

Comment: I posted the rest.